# Jquery: Delay and fade-in multiple divs onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein, onload

I am not very experienced with javascript but I asume this is not a difficult problem. Never the less I am lost and am wondering how to make multiple div's fade in with a delay when a page loads, say 5-10 divs using Jquery. The following is the code I am using and need but modified so I can load 5+ div's:

```
<script>
    $(".fade").hide(0).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000)
</script>​
```

Comment: This code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Gcq36/. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".fade, #anotherElement, #yetAnother, .etc").hide(0).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000)
```

It's called [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

That code should work fine *if* the ".fade" elements have already been parsed when it runs - which won't be the case if you have placed that script block in the `<head>`. If the script block is at the bottom of the body it will work, or if you put the code in a document ready handler so that it will run after the document has been parsed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".fade").hide(0).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/QHwge/

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to do this with javascript, but the examples here all seem to work fine.

Here is an example using CSS:

```
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   }

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: That's fine if you want to make something fade out when it's hovered over, but doesn't exactly work for making elements fade in after the page loads.

Comment: Move the opacity value to .fade{...} and add .fade to your element after page load it would.

Comment: Add `.fade` to your element after page load... with javascript?

Comment: Yes, unless :focus would make more sense (using the autofocus attribute of html5)